# OS independent C library for calculating time lapse?

Tags: c, time

So in my game I need to simulate the physics in a hardware independent manner.

I'm going to use a fixed time-step simulation, but I need to be able to calculate how much time is passing between calls.

I tried this and got nowhere:

```
#include <time.h>
double time_elapsed;
clock_t last_clocks = clock();
while (true) {
  time_elapsed = ( (double) (clock() - last_clocks) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  last_clocks = clock();
  printf("%f\n", time_elapsed);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [gettimeofday](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/gettimeofday.html) to get the number of seconds plus the number of microseconds since the Epoch. If you want the number of seconds, you can do something like this:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
float getTime()
{
    struct timeval time;
    gettimeofday(&time, 0);
    return (float)time.tv_sec + 0.000001 * (float)time.tv_usec;
}
```

**I misunderstood your question at first, but you might find the following method of making a fixed-timestep physics loop useful.**

There are two things you need to do to make a fixed-timestep physics loop.

First, you need to calculate the time between now and the last time you ran physics.

```
last = getTime();
while (running)
{
    now = getTime();
    // Do other game stuff
    simulatePhysics(now - last);
    last = now;
}
```

Then, inside of the physics simulation, you need to calculate a fixed timestep.

```
void simulatePhysics(float dt)
{
    static float timeStepRemainder; // fractional timestep from last loop
    dt += timeStepRemainder * SIZE_OF_TIMESTEP;

    float desiredTimeSteps = dt / SIZE_OF_TIMESTEP;
    int nSteps = floorf(desiredTimeSteps); // need integer # of timesteps

    timeStepRemainder = desiredTimeSteps - nSteps;

    for (int i = 0; i < nSteps; i++)
        doPhysics(SIZE_OF_TIMESTEP);

}
```

Using this method, you can give whatever is doing physics (doPhysics in my example) a fixed timestep, while keeping a synchronization between real time and game time by calculating the  right number of timesteps to simulate since the last time physics was run.

Comment: now - last keeps on returning 0. :( .

 float now = get_time();
  float time_elapsed = now - last_time;
                                                                  
  printf("%f\n", time_elapsed);
  
  last_time = now;  
 usleep(1000000); 

prints 0.00000, 0.0000, ...

Answer (score 0):

[`clock_gettime(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).